# openSSL - How do I set the issuer details?

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, self-signed

I am using the next command to create self signed digital signature certificate:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout myCert.pem -out homeMadeCrt/myCert_20140209_230846.pem -subj "/C=IL/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=companyName/CN=CommonName/GN=GivenName/SN=SureName/emailAddress=email@addresss.com/serialNumber=123456"`

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCert.pem -out myCert.p12 -password pass:foobar`

`openssl pkcs12 -in myCert.p12 -out myCert.crt -password pass:foobar`

Everything works great the only problem is that I need the issuer details to be different than the subject, but in this method they are the same.

Do you know I can I control the issuer details?

Answer (score 9):

The issuer field is the content of the subject field of the authority certificate that signed your certificate. Because you are using a self-signed certificate, your certificate is by definition both the certificate and the authority. That's why the subject field and the issuer field are the same.
If you want a different value, you should first set up a private CA, then sign your certificate with this CA. See for example:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zmiller/ca-howto/